# Lavary laravel menu not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am using Lavary's Laravel menu package for creating menus which is defined in  middleware named `frontMenu` and applied it using route grouping.However when I access the particular route, it says `Class 'App\Http\Middleware\Menu' not found`.I have also correctly added content on config/app.php as per documentation.My middleware code is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Service\PageService;
class frontMenu
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        Menu::make('myNavBar', function($menu){

                     $menu->add('Home');

                     $menu->add('About',    array('route'  => 'page.about'));

                     $menu->about->add('Who are we?', 'who-we-are');
                     $menu->about->add('What we do?', 'what-we-do');

                    $menu->add('services', 'services');
                    $menu->add('Contact',  'contact');

                    });



        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

what have I done wrong ?

Comment: use `App\Http\Middleware\Menu::make(...` or put `use App\Http\Middleware\Menu` on top as `use Closure`

Comment: @K.Toress ,I have already added facades for Menu on config/app.php as given in documentation https://github.com/lavary/laravel-menu .So I guess I don't need to do use App\Http\Middleware\Menu::make(...

Comment: then put `use Menu;` and check

Comment: @K.Toress,ah..you were right thank you

Answer (score 2):

I was missing `Use Menu;`.Thanks @K.Toress for assist